# How to count checked checkbox in Angular 7?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to count checked checkbox on my form that read data from the array. I tried a few methods but it's doesn't work. I never did this before and I don't know how it works. Can you guys guide me the way, please? I'm using Angular 7

**HTML**

```
<tr *ngFor="let p of product">
  <td class="text-left pl-3 py-1 font-small-2">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox m-0">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id={{p.label}} [(ngModel)]="count" (ngModelChange)="changed()">
      <label class="custom-control-label col-form-label" for={{p.label}}> 
           </label>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>{{p.name}}</td>
</tr>
<p>Product count {{count}}</p>
```

**Type Script**

```
product = [{
    name: 'Razer R1',
    label: 'item1'
  },
  {
    name: 'Razer R2',
    label: 'item2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Razer R3',
    label: 'item3'
  },
]
changed() {
  this.count = 0;
  this.product.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item);
    if (item['checked']) {
      this.count = this.count + 1;
    }
  })
}
```

I'm not quite sure that this is correct. So can you guide help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> HTML Code :-

```
<tr *ngFor="let p of product">
  <td class="text-left pl-3 py-1 font-small-2">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox m-0">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id={{p.label}} [(ngModel)]="p.checked" (ngModelChange)="changed()">
      <label class="custom-control-label col-form-label" for={{p.label}}> 
       </label>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>{{p.name}}</td>
</tr>
<br />
<br /> Total Items Checked :- {{count}}
```

> Angular Component Code:-

```
product = [{
    name: 'Razer R1',
    label: 'item1'
  },
  {
    name: 'Razer R2',
    label: 'item2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Razer R3',
    label: 'item3'
  },
]
changed() {
  this.count = 0;
  this.product.forEach(item => {
    if (item['checked']) {
      this.count = this.count + 1;
    }
  })
}
```

Note:- You need to replace `[(ngModel)]="count"` to  `[(ngModel)]="p.checked"` in HTML Section. please check [Link For output](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y4ckxw)

Comment: You're right but I'm not clear where you get checked from? "p.checked" and checked is showing an error not defined.

Comment: @LaCooler You have created a loop of an array of object and you are creating a dynamic element for that object `checked: true`  or  `checked: false`. based on that you are getting number of counts